# Remove first character of string with condition in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to remove the 0 that appears at the beginning of some observations for Zipcode in the following table:

[image]

I think the `sub` function is probably my best choice but I only want to do the replacement for observations that begin with 0, not all observations like the following does:

```
data_individual$Zipcode <-sub(".", "", data_individual$Zipcode)
```

Is there a way to condition this so it only removes the first character if the Zipcode starts with 0? Maybe grepl for those that begin with 0 and generate a dummy variable to use?

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can specify the `^0+` as pattern i.e. one or more 0s at the start (`^`) of the string instead of `.` (`.` in regex matches any character)

```
data_individual$Zipcode <- sub("^0+", "", data_individual$Zipcode)
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(stringr)
data_individual$Zipcode <- str_remove(data_individual$Zipcode, "^0+")
```

---

Another option without regex would be to convert to `numeric` as numeric values doesn't support prefix 0 (assuming all zipcodes include only digits)

```
data_individual$Zipcode <- as.numeric(data_individual$Zipcode)
```